# how to disable button for 3 seconds after button click and enable the button again

Tags: vb.net, button, timer

how to disable button for 3 seconds after button click and enable the button again by itself? VB.net

I want to disable the button for 3 seconds so users wont abuse the system.

Comment: What are you stuck on?  Disabling buttons? Waiting 3 seconds? Enabling? VB?

Comment: I'm stuck on how to add a timer to re-enable the button. @Plutonix

Comment: you dont know how to add a timer?  Its just like adding a button

Comment: How will I add it in my button click to re-enable the button after disabling it.
I managed to disable the button after clicking it. But not re-enabling.

Comment: `myButton.Enabled = Not myButton.Enabled`

Comment: So how are you gonna time it? @Plutonix

Comment: WinForms? WPF? WebForms?...

Comment: How does a `Timer` work?  Do you know?  If not, why not?  Have you made an effort to find out, e.g. check the MSDN documentation for the `Timer` class?  We don't expect you to know everything but we do expect that you'll at least make an effort to find out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> how to disable button for 3 seconds after button click and enable the
>   button again by itself?

In its simplest form:

```
Private Async Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Button1.Enabled = False

    ' ... do something ...

    Await Task.Delay(3000)

    Button1.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

If the "do something" part is time consuming, then maybe something more like:

```
Private Async Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Button1.Enabled = False

    Await Task.Run(Sub()

                       ' ... do something ...

                       System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000)
                   End Sub)

    Button1.Enabled = True
End Sub
```